# Por que ocorre o erro class expected?

Tags: java

Estou programando em Java no Android Studio e está ocorrendo um erro de **.class expected**:

```
package com.example.equacaodosegundograu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, total;
    EditText edittext2, edittext3;
    Button calc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        edittext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext3);
        calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                float M = float.parseFloat;
                float V = float.parseFloat(edittext3.getText().toString());
                float ec = (M * (V * V)) / 2;
                total.setText(Float.toString(ec));
            }
        })

    ;}
}
```

[image: imagem de onde ocorre o erro]

[image: todos os erros]

Answer (score 3):

**float** é um tipo primitivo, não possui métodos.

Métodos pertencem a classes, daí o erro ***.class expected***.

O método *parseFloat()* pertence à classe **Float**.

Altere

```
float V = float.parseFloat(edittext3.getText().toString());
```

para

```
float V = Float.parseFloat(edittext3.getText().toString());
```

Não esquecer de verificar/garantir que o conteúdo do edittext3 representa um float.

Ao nomear variáveis use nomes com significado.